# How to check if a table variable is empty in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, null, table-variable

This is a section of one of my stored procedure:

```
@dataInTable dbo.Table_Variable readonly,
....

AND (
    ( @dataInTable IS NULL )
    OR
    ( item IN ( SELECT T FROM @dataInTable ) )
)
```

`@dataInTable IS NULL` is wrong in syntax, error is

> Must declare the scalar variable "@dataInTable"

So I change it to:

```
(SELECT T FROM @dataInTable) IS NULL
```

This works but if `@dataInTable` has more than 1 item, I get an error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Understandable, so I change it to:

```
(SELECT TOP(1) T FROM @ProgramRatings) IS NULL
```

Works perfectly, what I have is performance concern.

I am wondering, if there has an easier way to check whether a table variable is empty, like

```
AND (
    ( @dataInTable IS EMPTY )
    OR
    ( item IN ( SELECT T FROM @dataInTable ) )
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For check if table variable is empty, just use EXISTS as already mentioned by other people,

**but**

if you differ empty set from unknown set - then you have no choice - you have to introduce extra variable which states if empty set is really empty or unknown.

```
declare @dataInTableIsUnknown BIT

...

AND (
    ( @dataInTableIsUnknown = 1 )
    OR
    ( item IN ( SELECT T FROM @dataInTable ) )
)
```

Answer (score 35):

Table variables are different from scalar variables so `@dataInTable IS NULL` is not allowed as you mentioned.  I would suggest the following:

```
EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @dataInTable)
```

The following also may make sense for your situation if you actually care to know the count:

```
DECLARE @dataCount int = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @dataInTable)
IF @dataCount = 0 -- Empty
```

Answer (score 11):

There's always `exists`.

For example:

```
select 'Yep'
where exists (select 1 from @dataInTable)
```

Comment: +1 `EXISTS` can be more efficient than `COUNT` as it stops after the first row.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the exist but it cannot used inside a select condition: AND (
    ( I CANNOT PLACE Exist HERE )
    OR
    ( item IN ( SELECT T FROM @dataInTable ) )
). Do you know the correct syntax

Comment: @EricYin You are probably looking for `CASE` if you want to use it in a `SELECT`. Difficult to know what you are doing based on the fragments you have posted so far.

Comment: @EricYin I don't see why you can't use `exists` as a drop in replacement for what you currently have posted in your question: `@dataInTable IS EMPTY` is replaced with `exists (select 1 from @dataInTable)` if this is not the case you should add more context to your question...

Comment: :( My bad, I wrote EXIST(select 1 from @dataInTable) and got error. I have no idea why it shows as blue in my management studio, so I did not find this typo.

Comment: @EricYin You do see that it's `exists` ending with an `s`, right? You've said "exist" twice now, and that would not be correct.

Comment: @EricYin - Doesn't show up blue for me. Sure you didn't type `EXIT`? Maybe your `S` key is wearing out!